# With pyspark Bucketizer, why am I getting IllegalArgumentException: Bucketizer_16c8b99a7c59 parameter splits given invalid value?

Tags: pyspark

Given

```py
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

    df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [{'score': 0.056906660760916945},
     {'score': 0.014312104993006614},
     {'score': 0.019505725666714737},
     {'score': 0.05695818453036461},
     {'score': 0.004712143467991172},
     {'score': 0.01950581558579922},
     {'score': 0.0},
     {'score': 0.004479459183469148},
     {'score': 0.0},
     {'score': 0.0002634215537602458},
     {'score': 1.6},
     {'score': 0.0002634215537602458}], ["score"]
    )
    
    splits = [0, 0.7, 0.21, 1]
    bucket_df = Bucketizer(
        splits=splits, inputCol="score", outputCol="score_bucket"
    ).transform(df.where(F.col("score").isNotNull()))
    bucket_df.groupBy("score_bucket").count().show()
```

getting

```py
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-94-19c8c78fe553> in <cell line: 15>()
         15 bucket_df = Bucketizer(
         16     splits=splits, inputCol="score", outputCol="score_bucket"
    ---> 17 ).transform(df.where(F.col("score").isNotNull()))
         18 bucket_df.groupBy("score_bucket").count().show()
    
    ~/Downloads/2023-06-01-spark/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in transform(self, dataset, params)
        260                 return self.copy(params)._transform(dataset)
        261             else:
    --> 262                 return self._transform(dataset)
        263         else:
        264             raise TypeError("Params must be a param map but got %s." % type(params))
    
    ~/Downloads/2023-06-01-spark/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _transform(self, dataset)
        395         assert self._java_obj is not None
        396 
    --> 397         self._transfer_params_to_java()
        398         return DataFrame(self._java_obj.transform(dataset._jdf), dataset.sparkSession)
        399 
    
    ~/Downloads/2023-06-01-spark/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _transfer_params_to_java(self)
        169         for param in self.params:
        170             if self.isSet(param):
    --> 171                 pair = self._make_java_param_pair(param, self._paramMap[param])
        172                 self._java_obj.set(pair)
        173             if self.hasDefault(param):
    
    ~/Downloads/2023-06-01-spark/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _make_java_param_pair(self, param, value)
        158         java_param = self._java_obj.getParam(param.name)
        159         java_value = _py2java(sc, value)
    --> 160         return java_param.w(java_value)
        161 
        162     def _transfer_params_to_java(self) -> None:
    
    ~/.python_venvs/pandars310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1319 
       1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    -> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
       1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1323 
    
    ~/Downloads/2023-06-01-spark/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py in deco(*a, **kw)
        173                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
        174                 # JVM exception message.
    --> 175                 raise converted from None
        176             else:
        177                 raise
    
    IllegalArgumentException: Bucketizer_aff53d93ca5b parameter splits given invalid value [0.0,0.7,0.21,1.0].
```

Answer (score 0):

### After trying a few things realized my bug was really silly!

I had

```py
splits = [0, 0.7, 0.21, 1]
```

but I meant

```py
splits = [0, 0.07, 0.21, 1]
               ^
```

### That almost fixed it but then I had one more error,

which was over 100 lines long,

paraphrasing it, I noticed the detail that my bounds were too constricting.

```
23/09/13 20:50:45 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 15.0 in stage 73.0 (TID 108)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (Bucketizer$$Lambda$3807/0x00000008014b99b8: (double) => double).
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Feature value 1.6 out of Bucketizer bounds [0.0, 1.0]. Check your features, or loosen the lower/upper bound constraints.
...
23/09/13 20:50:45 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 15 in stage 73.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
23/09/13 20:50:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.0 in stage 73.0 (TID 107) (10.50.171.196 executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
```

And using something like

```py
splits = [0, 0.07, 0.21, 1, 2]
```

fixed my second problem!